# Texture mapping on a 3D face from 2D face image

Tags: image-processing, algorithms, opencv, 3d, reconstruction

I have 3D points (xyz) of a face image and I have 2D face image of the same person.

The 3D points of the face are such that If I project the points to 2D plane, it matches with the 2D face image.

I want to map the color information on to the 3D image.
So after mapping I will have the texture of each point.
I want to do it using Matlab/OpenCV.

Can anyone suggest any algorithm or refer some source for me to start.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is more in the image synthesis / computer graphics domain (technically, it's "texture mapping") than it is in the image-processing domain, so it's not obvious that Matlab/OpenCV are going to have any relevant supporting functionality.

If I had the same problem in my (preferred) Python/SciPy/Matplotlib world, I'd probably see if [mplot3d's surface plotting](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots) was up to the job (passing the 2D image as the `facecolors` parameter).  However general experience is that it doesn't deal well with 100s x 100s size grids, only a few 10s x 10s.  Sorry, I don't know what Matlab's equivalent is.  (And if mplot3d wasn't up to the job I'd be looking at the mlab VTK wrapping's [texture mapping](http://enthought-dev.117412.n3.nabble.com/MayaVI-Texture-Map-td4026003.html) support).